# Jquery unexpected token when using a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm quite new to Javascript and HTML, so I suspect I've made a rookie mistake, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a dropdown menu in my `html` document, and when the button next to it is pressed, I'd like to use `svg` to draw a regular polygon and add it to a `div`. Unfortunately, I keep getting "unexpected token" on the curly bracket on the second line. Here is the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#pull-me').click(function(){
        $('.panel').slideToggle('slow');
    })

    $('.polygon').function(){
        $('#updatebutton').click(function(){
            var n = parseInt($('#nvalue').val());
            var coords = '';
            for (i=0; i< n; i++){
            coords += (250 + 225*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i/n)).toString() + ',' + (250 + 225*Math.cos(2*Math.PI*i/n)).toString() + ',';
            };
            coords = coords.substring(0,coords.length - 1);
        )};
        var $drawing = '<svg height="500" width="500" id="shape"> <!-- The center of the polygon is at the point 250,250 --> <polygon points=' +coords+ 'style="fill:#FFF;stroke:#000;stroke-width:3" /> Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG. </svg>';
        $('.polygon').append($drawing); 
}
)};
```

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Updated: Here is some of the html code:

```
<div class='n-and-operations'>
<h4>Select a value of n</h4>
<select id='nvalue'>
    <option> 3 </option>
    <option> 4 </option>
    <option> 5 </option>
    <option> 6 </option>
    <option> 7 </option>
    <option> 8 </option>
</select>
<button id='updatebutton'> Update </button>
</div>

<div class='polygon'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write event handler on html objects but we can't call plain function() on html objects as you wrote on `$('.polygon')` object as it will not call at all so i.e reason for `unexpected token` error.

Second is you are initialized variable `coords` inside click event function, but trying to access outside of the function.

Try with below code

```
    var drawPolygon = function(coords){
        var $drawing = '<svg height="500" width="500" id="shape"> <!-- The center of the polygon is at the point 250,250 --> <polygon points=' +coords+ 'style="fill:#FFF;stroke:#000;stroke-width:3" /> Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG. </svg>';
        $('.polygon').append($drawing); 
}

$('#updatebutton').click(function(){
            var n = parseInt($('#nvalue').val());
            var coords = '';
            for (i=0; i< n; i++){
            coords += (250 + 225*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i/n)).toString() + ',' + (250 + 225*Math.cos(2*Math.PI*i/n)).toString() + ',';
            };
            coords = coords.substring(0,coords.length - 1);
            drawPolygon(coords)
        )};
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: This works great. I had to make a few minor change, such as adding a space in the "coords" string. Is there a way to use `replaceWith()` instead of append? I tried just replacing append with replaceWith, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Update: I used `$('.polygon').replaceWith('<div class="polygon">' + $drawing + '</div>');` . Not really the cleanest, but I suppose it works for now.

Comment: Cool!, If my answer solves your problem mark it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't call plain `function()` on `$('.polygon')` object. Get rid of the second line of code and its closing bracket as it doesn't do anything...

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. Unfortunately, the shape doesn't update though. If I change the value coming from the dropdown menu, the shape doesn't redraw itself. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Can you provide us with some more of your code? Hard to say from this snippet.

Comment: I added some html code, and a few extra lines that I have in the js code!

Comment: I got thing mostly sorted out thanks to an answer above. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice you are pasting the coords to the string out of scope. I already upvoted for the advice above

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't need the that second line at all, and the bracket associated with it on the second last line.

The click handler code only gets called when the click is actioned, so that isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. Unfortunately, the shape doesn't update though. If I change the value coming from the dropdown menu, the shape doesn't redraw itself. Do you know why this might be?